# PHP - MYSQLI : dynamically select attributes from db and display in dropdown issues

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to select category names from my db and display them in a dropdown. I cannot see why my code is not working.
The drop down literally only displays "select category" and nothing else. It also makes all the fields after it disappear.

HTML/PHP

```
<select name="cats">
    <option>Choose cuisine</option>
    <?php
        $get_cats = "SELECT * FROM Rest_Category";
        $run_cats = mysqli_query($dbc,$get_cats);
        while ($row_cats = mysql_fetch_array($run_cats)) {
            $CategoryID = $row_cats['CategoryID'];
            $Cuisine_category = $row_cats['Cuisine_category'];
            echo"<option value='$CategoryID'>$Cuisine_category</option>";
            //echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['Cuisine_category'] .  "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

TABLE

```
   CREATE TABLE `Rest_Category` (
   `CategoryID` smallint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Cuisine_category` enum('African','Alcohol','American','Asian Fusion','Breakfast',
   'British Roast','Bubble Tea','Burgers','Cakes & Desserts',
   'Caribbean','Chicken','Chinese','Coffee','Cupcakes','European','Fish &   Chips',
 'Five Guys','Fried Chicken','Gourmet','Greek','Ice Cream','Italian','Indian',
 'Jamaican','Juice','Krispy Kreme','Turkish') NOT NULL,
 `Category_img` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

where have i gone wrong?

Comment: What do you see when you view the source in your browser? What does the generated HTML for that select box look like? Add that to the question as well.

Comment: Also shouldn't you have `mysqli_fetch_array()`? You currently have `mysql_fetch_array()`. Notice the missing `i`!

Comment: @Keeleon thank you. that was my mistake, it works perfect

Comment: If you use the more modern, object-oriented approach this sort of mistake is almost impossible to make.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is that you are using `mysql_fetch_array()` when it should be `mysqli_fetch_array()`. Notice the missing `i`.